# Android Image masking

Tags: bitmap, android-camera, android-imageview, masking

I want to capture two bitmaps and put them on top of each other. The top image should be movable like seek bar. The movable bitmap(top image) should mask and unmask the below bitmap. Is this possible or not ? please let me know.